# How to use GY-86 i2c module (MS5611 baro and HMC5883 mag) with MAMBA F405 MK2 in iNav?

Tags: inav

I soldered this module to Mamba F405 by I2C pins. It worked successfully with Betaflight but is not working after I installed iNav 6.0.0 (battery is connected).

I see red baro and mag icons in configurator.

Can I use this module with iNav?

Result of status command in CLI:

```
# status
INAV/MAMBAF405_2022B 6.0.0 Sep 26 2023 / 18:09:32 (7e7efe4a)
GCC-10.2.1 20201103 (release)
System Uptime: 23 seconds
Current Time: 2041-06-28T01:04:00.000+00:00
Voltage: 15.37V (4S battery - OK)
CPU Clock=168MHz, GYRO=ICM42605, ACC=ICM42605
STM32 system clocks:
  SYSCLK = 168 MHz
  HCLK   = 168 MHz
  PCLK1  = 42 MHz
  PCLK2  = 84 MHz
Sensor status: GYRO=OK, ACC=OK, MAG=UNAVAILABLE, BARO=UNAVAILABLE, RANGEFINDER=NONE, OPFLOW=NONE, GPS=OK
Stack size: 6144, Stack address: 0x10010000, Heap available: 1828
I2C Errors: 0, config size: 8915, max available config: 131072
ADC channel usage:
   BATTERY : configured = ADC 1, used = ADC 1
      RSSI : configured = none, used = none
   CURRENT : configured = ADC 2, used = ADC 2
  AIRSPEED : configured = none, used = none
System load: 8, cycle time: 518, PID rate: 1930, RX rate: 9, System rate: 9
Arming disabled flags: CAL HWFAIL RX CLI DSHOTBEEPER
OSD: MAX7456 [30 x 16]
VTX: band: A, chan: 1, power: 1 (25 mW), freq: 5865 MHz
```